# Стабильность и вариативность признаков согласных

Tags: фонемология

Чем объясняется относительная стабильность признаков согласных по месту и способу образования и значительная вариативность таких признаков, как глухость/звонкость и твердость/мягкость?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, фонетической близостью, т.е. гораздо меньшим измененим речевых органов и работы соответвующих мышц. 
В отношении признака звонкости-глухости - это даже обсуждать не приходится, такое чередование втречается во многих языках, ведь разница всего лишь в более интенсивном выдохе, заставляющем колебаться голосовые связки.
Вот палатализация как дифференцирующий признак - явление довольно специфическое и еще более специфичным для славянских (даже - восточнославянских) является чередования по твердости-мягкости. Но, видимо, для русского языка постоянный позиционный переход твердого в мягкий и наоборот как раз и породил внутреннее представление о "близости" оппозиционной пары твердый-мягкий.